# vb.net devexpress datagridview add values in rows

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have Devexpress Grid control in my form, I would like to add values in rows manually, but when I entered value in cell after press enter, I see nothing in cell.

I do not understand why, do we need code for this? I dont think soo. See pic here [image]

Comment: What is the datasource of the this grid control and how are you adding row values in the data source so that it reflect back when you add them to the data source??

Comment: I want to add values via manually

Answer (score 1):

The GridControl does not maintain an internal data source and should be bound to a data source. If you do not want to provide a data source for the GridControl, you should handle the [CustomUnboundColumnData event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) to supply the value for a cell. You can also try using the [UnboundSource data component](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument116190).

Answer (score 0):

**Reference:** [Add Unbound Data to a Data-Aware Control (XtraGrid, XtraPivotGrid)](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2386)

> In most cases data-aware DevExpress .NET controls contain **bound
>   columns/fields** that display data from bound data sources. In Grid
>   Control and PivotGrid controls, it is possible to add **unbound
>   columns/fields** that can display arbitrary data. Unbound columns are
>   not bound to any field in a data source. You can provide data for
>   these fields by specifying a [formula (string expression)](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument6211.aspx) used to
>   evaluate values or by handling an event

If you want to bind data without the currently existing ready-to-use source, use the [UnboundSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument116190.aspx) component as Brendon already suggested.